# Fedora and Empty External Hard Drive

Tags: fedora

Here is what happened:
I tried to install Fedora and my external hard drive was connected to my desktop computer. After I ran Fedora successfully, my external hard drive shows empty. I didn't delete any file but now I can't see the content of my external hard drive. Can anyone suggest me any solution to see the content again? I ran some recovery software and it shows all the files are there, but it is now taking more than 2 weeks (continuously) and the scan is not finished yet. Does anyone know a better solution to this? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Specifics are your friend - if "some" application takes a long time, there's "some" reason for it. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/741696/edit) your question to add more context and details.